# how to solve SQL syntax error?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
try {
    String req = "INSERT INTO nouvelle_installation" +
      "values('" + ref + "','" + today + "','" + check + "','" + nbligne +
      "','" + tligne + "','" + categorie + "','" + instal + "','" + cin +
      "','" + user + "','" + prenom+"','" + numC + "','" + num + "','" + voie +
      "','" + tvoie + "','" + imm + "','" + app + "','" + etage +
      "','" + codep + "')"; 

    Statement m = s.getCon().createStatement();  
    m.executeUpdate(req);
} catch (SQLException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Erreur de syntaxe près 
>       de ''aaa','2012-04-10',' ','------','---------------','-------',
>       'Nouvelle Installati' à la ligne 1

Comment: SQL injection; check it out. This is so hard to read without reasonable whitespace.

Comment: Or more directly: Parameterized SQL Queries using prepared Statements: use them to avoid **both** SQL injection attacks **and** the problem that you're having right now.

Comment: You use quotes within quotes. You have to escape those with a backslash. `"This is a \"String\" literal`.

Comment: You should use a java.sql.PreparedStatement. Have a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester Where? I don't see that. It's possible--it's dizzying to read this mess, but I don't see any attempts at literal double-quotes.

Comment: @DaveNewton Oh yeah I read the question before there was syntax highlighting and I was confused between the single and double quotes :) nvm then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use prepared statements instead of concatenating your statement.

Also prepared statements is faster than Statement.

You are missing a space between your table-name and the keyword `values`.

Comment: I used the PreparedStatement and I got an error                          String req2="INSERT INTO nouvelle_installation" + "values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";                                             com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Erreur de syntaxe prÃ¨s de '?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)' Ã  la ligne 1

Comment: I used the PreparedStatement and I got an error :  com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Erreur de syntaxe prÃ¨s de '?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)' Ã  la ligne 1                                                                                             String req2="INSERT INTO nouvelle_installation" + "values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

Comment: @rohit: Did you just copy that last sentence from my post? ;-)

Comment: @Peter Lang : No, but strangely i typed it as it is you typed:)

Answer (score 2):

As others said, use [prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) instead of concatenating your statement.

This would prevent [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), and your current problem:

```
"INSERT INTO nouvelle_installation" + "values" ...
```

results in

```
"INSERT INTO nouvelle_installationvalues" ...
```

You are missing a space between your table-name and the keyword `values`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put a space between the "INSERT INTO nouvelle_installation" + "values(...
or the string will appear to look like

```
"INSERT INTO nouvelle_installationvalues("...
```

So it should look like this

```
"INSERT INTO nouvelle_installation" + " values(...
```

Answer (score 1):

As already someone as pointed out, this code is subject to Sql Injection Attacks.
However the first error visible in your query is the space missing before the `values` keyword

Answer (score 0):

You have a quote following `num` and one before `voie` with no comma between them. Is that what you wanted?

```
... + "','" + num  + "'"   +
      "'"   + voie + "','" + tvoie + ...
```

This effectively gives you `,'NUM''VOIE','`.

You also have no space before the `values` keyword.